# knockoutjs dynamic template binding with dynamic property name

Tags: knockout.js

Following is the sample taken from knockoutjs website tutorial. My problem is bit more complex and i want to create reusable wizards, controls or components for our web application.

Following scenario represent one a very common problem I am facing that is template binding is different from view model property. If we look at person-template  is bind by 'name' property which will come from view modal with 'name' property. Now imagine a situation where I have two view model quite similar but has some property names are different.(As in case of buyer and seller with property names 'BuyerName', 'SellerName', Is there any way I can create template, so I can bind to dynamic properties.

I mean in this example will work with both buyer and seller. any suggestions or any idea will be welcome.

My problem is more complex than this and I am quite stuck.

Thanks.

```
<h2>Participants</h2>
Here are the participants:
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'person-template', data: buyer }"></div>
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'person-template', data: seller }"></div>

<script type="text/html" id="person-template">
     // Now name property is bind, where as view model has two
     // properties named BuyerName and SellerName, so it is not going to work.
     <h3 data-bind="text: name"></h3>
    <p>Credits: <span data-bind="text: credits"></span></p>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
     function MyViewModel() {
         this.buyer = { BuyerName: 'Franklin', credits: 250 };
         this.seller = { SellerName: 'Mario', credits: 5800 };
     }
     ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
</script>
```

Comment: How do you get your data? are they predefined or via AJAX call?

Comment: Hi ebram, I am getting the data by Ajax call. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well a classic Polymorphism problem then

You have to chain your templates, the base template person-template should only contain data binding that both BuyerViewModel and SellerViewModel has.

Any aditional bindings has to be located in a buyer-template and a seller-template

Something like

```
<script id="buyer-template" type="text/html">
   <!-- Fields shared by both classes -->
   <div data-bind="template: { data: $data, template: 'person-template' }></div> 
   <!-- fields for buyer only -->
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, yes it will work like this, but i have to copy the following code for both the templates as only difference between them is just property name - <h3 data-bind="text: name"></h3>. Is there is way property name could be passed dynamically, because it will save lots of template and code duplication. Thanks to show how to use template within the template. Thanks again.

Comment: Rename BuyerName and SellerName to Name? :D

Comment: Yes, it will work also,but then you need to change transform the data model, originally created. You need to go through all the objects and change the property name either on the server or on the client. Which is workable but some work and was trying to write the unnecessary code. Thanks very much for suggestion. May this is the only option. Thanks Again.

Comment: Use mapping plugin is a option, add a computed, etc. Lots of ways of doing it

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you get your data via AJAX call to the server, I suggest to use the *magical* binding object to put your logic in it:

In case of your simple example you can add new property to the object model you get from the server and use that new property against your html binding. Kindly check [customizing object construction using create](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html#customizing_object_construction_using_create).

Or you go with simple little long way and define the new model you want by your hand then bind the data you get from the server to the new model(again you can use `create` in mapping object).